# How can I turn symbols and whitespace into a 2D list? Best way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine that I have the follow in a .txt file:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|   |     |     |
|   |     |     |
|   |     +=====+
+---+     |  |  |
|   |     |  |  |
|   +-+   +=====+
|   | |   |     |
|   | +-+ |     |
|   |   | |     |
|   |   +-+     |
|   |     |_____|
|   |     |     |
+---+-----+-----+
```

What is the best way I can turn this into a 2D list that also includes the whitespace?

I wrote a function that will print it as a string.. But I simply do not know how to make this thing work. I'm just stumped.

Comment: this almost identical question has been asked like 5 times in the last week ... time to test your google skills

Comment: Try `[list(line) for line in s.splitlines()]`

Comment: show us your code. what did your code do? what is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [[letter for letter in line] for line in f.read().split('\n')]
```

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to stackoverflow. If you are satisfied please accept my answer by clicking the check button to the left.

Comment: Done. I will try to sharpen my skills and hopefully be able to answer questions like you do.

Comment: Good luck. One thing to point out here is that the Python string implementation is similar to C in that it is essentially a null-terminated array of characters. As such, you can access letters within a string using bracket notation, where `"my string"[0]` returns `'m'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.readlines()` function, like so:

```
with open('in.txt') as input_file:
    data = input_file.readlines()

assert data[0][0] == '+'
assert data[3][4] == '|'
```